# Create V8 instance in node.js with low latency

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I have a node.js webserver which is supposed to execute a javascript-String which is passed at runtime with low latency. I am basically looking for an node.js version of the following java code:

```
import com.eclipsesource.v8.V8;

public class MainC {

private static V8 v8;   

private static int result;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long time0 = System.nanoTime();
    createRuntime();       
    long time1 = System.nanoTime();   

    String script = "x(0,10000); "
        + "function x(y,z) { "
        + "     if (z>0) {"
        + "         return x(y+1,z-1); "
        + "     } else {"
        + "         return y;"
        + "     } "
        + "}"
        + ""; 

    simulateHTTPRequestAndExucuteScript(script);
    long time2 = System.nanoTime();          

    System.out.println("Result: " + result);        
    System.out.println("Time for 'createRuntime()' : " + ((time1-time0)/1000000.0) + " ms");
    System.out.println("Time for 'executeIntScript()' : " + ((time2-time1)/1000000.0) + " ms");
}

private static void createRuntime() {
    v8 = V8.createV8Runtime();   
}

private static void simulateHTTPRequestAndExucuteScript(String s) {
    result = v8.executeIntScript(s); 
}

}
```

which outputs:

```
Result: 10000
Time for 'createRuntime()' : 741.709313 ms
Time for simulateHTTPRequestAndExucuteScript()' : 0.888719 ms
```

Runtime creation and execution of the script are two separated tasks. Note, that the actual execution time for 10000 recursive calls is < 1ms. The comparably long time for initializing the runtime is not important, because this can be done before the string is passed.

How can V8 runtime creation and low latency javascript code injection be done with nodes.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [vm module](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) of nodejs?

```
var vm = require('vm');
var script = "result = x(0,10000); "
    + "function x(y,z) { "
    + "     if (z>0) {"
    + "         return x(y+1,z-1); "
    + "     } else {"
    + "         return y;"
    + "     } "
    + "}"
    + ""; 
var context = {result: null};

vm.createContext(context);

vm.runInContext(script, context);
console.log(context.result);
```

Answer (score 0):

eh.... node.js IS a v8 runtime wrapper.
you don't need to create, inject and so on with node.js
read the basic nodejs about page: https://nodejs.org/en/about/
basically you write javascript, run it via node.js (which again, is v8 with extra c++ libs wrapped with js code) and thats it.

in your case, you main js file that you run via nodejs will do that js code you have (that function (x) ....) and invoke it how many times you want.

to run the js file just do "node my-jsfile.js"

thats all.

Comment: The problem is that this takes several 100 ms on my computer. Therefore I am looking for a separation of initializing V8 and execution of a js file, like it is done in the java code

Comment: i'm not sure you understand what v8 and nodejs is, and in your java code you are not counting the time it takes to initialize your java jvm so its a bluff. bringing up a nodejs instance takes time. once it is up, you can open a socket and ask for incoming requests from whatever other project you got (lets say java), when a request to the nodejs comes, it can handle it right away and not wait for v8 to startup as it is already running, and return the ouput again, via socket.

Comment: I changed the code to make more clear what I mean. Between `long time0 = System.nanoTime();` and `long time1 = System.nanoTime();` V8 is initialized. This takes 741ms. The actual script that will be executed is not known at this stage. Between `long time1 = System.nanoTime();` and `long time2= System.nanoTime();`, the script is created and executed. This takes 0,8ms. The use case I am aiming for is: 1) Webserver starts. 2) Webserver initializes V8 instances and waits for request. 3) Incoming httprequest has js-code as String as parameter and executes in V8 ->Minimal time for answering request.

Comment: child_process.fork() creates a new node instance. You can pass it a JS file, and communicate via send();
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options

Comment: @chrisvanhooser can you write the code explicitly? I only found that fork requires the js code. send() doesn't inject the js-code. It can only communicate with code that is already there.